# Implementing Google Checkout in a website (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

How to implement Google checkout in a website?

Also provide how to create the test merchant in Google checkout for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google Checkout API and read [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_NET.html) / [faq](https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/).